# How can I grab browser information such as the current URL opened on my computer with Python

Tags: python, url, browser, proxy, backend

I want to know the current URL opened on my computer. For example, I currently have Stack Overflow opened I would like to write a script that tells me the URL and some other information. I also looked into proxy servers where I can possibly read the proxy logs but I was wondering if alternatives exist.

Comment: What browser are you using on what operating system?  There are likely to be different ways to get this information in different contexts.

Comment: Google Chrome on Mac